# RAILS What kind of relation should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

in my project i got stuck in a one point: Project should be able to use at least one language, and language has many projects. I created such models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer, counter_cache: true
  has_many :languages

  validates :developer, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, presence: true

end
```

AND:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

I added 3 languages to DB.
Now i should be able to create a project with certain language:

```
p = Project.create :developer_id=>"1", :language_id=>"2", :name=>"Project 1", :description=>"Sample project"
```

It says that:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'language_id' for Project.
```

Well I have language with such ID then why shouldnt it be able to add one. It might be the problem with languages -> they have no projects, but have relation: has_many: projects

Looking forward to hear from you guys:

EDIT:
now it looks like:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer, counter_cache: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages

  validates :developer, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, presence: true

end
```

I used `rails g migration CreateProjectsLanguages project:references language:references`

it returns:

```
p.languages.build(:name => "English")
PG::UndefinedTable: BŁĄD:  relacja "languages_projects" nie istnieje
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"languages_projects"'::re...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"languages_projects"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: BŁĄD:  relacja "languages_projects" nie istnieje
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"languages_projects"'::re...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"languages_projects"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

It looks like it cannot find relation between them(maybe the association table should look different)

Comment: You first attempt was correct, in you second attempt you misspelled the method name, it is has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: You have to use the associative table, the has_many method don't add a foreign key, instead it uses the foreign key from the related model, it is for a one to many relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an associative table for many to many relationships. In rails you can map the entities with has_many :models, through: associative_table_name.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :language_projects
end

class LanguageProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :language_projects
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

In your case, you may generate model and migration for the associative table:

```
rails g model LanguageProject project:references language:references
```

If you don't need to use the associative table as a model you may map the entities directly with has_and_belongs_to_many.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

In this case you can generate a migration only. You will get only the empty husk, so you have to edit the file manually

```
rails g migration CreateLanguagesProjectsJoinTable

class CreateLanguagesProjectsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :languages_projects, id: false do |t|
       t.integer :language_id
       t.integer :project_id
     end
  end
end
```

Then you should be able to associate the models this way

```
p = Project.new(:name => 'myproj')
p.languages.build(:name => 'ruby')
p.save
```

Comment: can u take a look now?

Comment: Im kinda lost with the migration name, let me check

Comment: It didnt work with CreateProjectsLanguages too. It fails when i try to build with 'p.languages.build(:name => "English")' same error occurs

Comment: I think rails guess the name of the associative table by alphabetical order of the related models, so it must be called LanguagesProjects. Or you may set the :join_table option explicitly has_and_belongs_to_many :languages, :join_table => 'projects_languages'

Comment: Ok, it worked. How can i now use it? Like:   = project.language.name   im kind of not sure about this solution, because later i would like to display projects which use only english for example

Comment: You don't have project.language, but project.languages, since it may have more than one

Comment: You are right, I am getting closer. So:  now = project.languages.name shows  Language: Language, i tryend languages[0] but it returns association link

Comment: to make a query like all projects that use english, for example, you would have to make a join (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

Comment: You must get familiar with active record query builder

Comment: Isn't there a simple way just to disp language used for project?

Comment: for this you may simply iterate over the p.languages array, rails will make the join for you. eg. p.languages.each{|lang| puts(lang.name)}

Comment: What do you mean ? if you try iterating like I said above, what happens ?

Comment: nice one, It displays: [#<Language id: 4, name: "English", created_at: "2015-12-13 16:10:18", updated_at: "2015-12-13 16:10:18">]  so it works ill try to find out how to disp "English" only

Comment: well, it is not a trivial query, try something like project.joins(:languages).where("not exists (select 1 from languages lang where lang.id = languages_projects.language_id and lang.name <> 'english')")

Comment: Sure im kinda new here and forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

Use [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). Their mechanisms are the same, except `has_many :through` has additional model.

Comment: Thanks,
I've heard about has many :through but didnt know the secound one. Hope it helps :)